# naming columns of DataFrame created from CountVectorizer Vector

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm creating to create spam/ham classifier. First I took all the emails and entered them to vector.

Then I used sklearn's `CountVectorizer` to count words over all the mails, and I got the following matrix:

```
>> print(vector.shape)
>> print(type(vector))
>> print(vector.toarray())

(2551, 48746)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
[[2 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [2 0 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [2 1 1 ... 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

If try to change the vector to DataFrame, I get:

```
>> df_X = pd.DataFrame(vector.toarray())

      0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      ...  48737  48738  48739  48740  48741  48742  48743  48744  48745
0         2      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
1         2      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
2         0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
3         1      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      4      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
4         3      0      1      0      0      0      0      0      0  ...      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0      0
5
```

The problem is that I want to have meaningful names for the columns (not 0,1,2,...,48745).

If I run `print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)`, I get:

```
>> print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
{u'74282760403': 10172, u'makinglight': 34440, u'localizes': 33864, u'sowell': 43338, u'e4c8b2940d2': 22109, u'juob22381': 32587, u'31c6d68fa597d411b04d00e02965883bd239fb': 7072, u'20020918154734': 5469, u'spiders': 43495, u'ftrain': 24856, u'hanging': 30009, u'woody': 48041, u'000093': 18, u'1a724ef5': 4703, u'05dc347c66': 1771, u'g93ba2f21504': 28071, u'g16mteg13192': 25103, u'7f08f1c2c4': 10578, u'g974xhk18362': 28334, u'g85bc1j10899': 26181,...}
```

This is the full code:

```
import os,glob
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer 

folder_path = 'easy_ham/'
files_text_arr = []
files_text_arr_y = []

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(folder_path, '*')):
  with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    files_text_arr.append(text)
    files_text_arr_y.append(0)

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(encoding='latin-1')
vectorizer.fit(files_text_arr)

vector = vectorizer.transform(files_text_arr)
print(vector.shape)
print(type(vector))
print(vector.toarray())
#print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)    

df_X = pd.DataFrame(vector.toarray())
df_y = pd.DataFrame({'spam':files_text_arr_y})
print(df_X)
```

How can I change the names of the columns to the words of the emails?

P.S. I use the emails from [this website](https://spamassassin.apache.org/old/publiccorpus/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the method `get_feature_names()` and then assign it to the columns of the dataframe that was created by the output of `toarray()` method.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
corpus = [
    'This is the first document.',
    'This document is the second document.',
    'And this is the third one.',
    'Is this the first document?',
]
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)
print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())

print(X.toarray())
```

Output

```
[u'and', u'document', u'first', u'is', u'one', u'second', u'the', u'third', u'this']
[[0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 2 0 1 0 1 1 0 1]
 [1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1]
 [0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1]]

df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())
df.columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
df
```

Output

```
    and document    first   is  one second  the third   this
 0   0      1        1      1    0    0       1    0    1
 1   0      2        0      1    0    1       1    0    1
 2   1      0        0      1    1    0       1    1    1
 3   0      1        1      1    0    0       1    0    1
```